# Issue with Injecting strongly typed configuration setting in dot net core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

We have a common class library project in which there is a class called say MyClass which implements IMyClass.

```
public class MyClass : IMyClass
{       
    private readonly string _myConfigPath;     

    public TimeSheet(MyConfigPath myConfigPath)
    {            
        _myConfigPath= myConfigPath.Value;
    }
    public void GetData(int id)
    {
         var values= _myConfigPath;
    }
}
public interface IMyClass
{
    void GetData(int id);
}
```

And my class MyConfigPath is extending from ConfigInjector.ConfigurationSetting abstract calss.

```
public class MyConfigPath  : ConfigurationSetting<string>
{

}
```

In older projects we were using AutoFac to inject the configuration settings with ConfigInjector.

But now we are on a new project based upon .Net Core2.1 and we have to use business logic written in MyClass.

Although I am able to inject IMyClass type in my new projects's controller like this

```
   services.ConfigurePOCO<MyConfigPath>(configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:MyConfigPath"));
 services.AddTransient<IMyClass , MyClass>();
```

but the values assigned to _myConfigPath is still null because we haven't provided any configuration info for configinjector.

I have tried to follow 
[StrathWeb Blog](https://www.strathweb.com/2016/09/strongly-typed-configuration-in-asp-net-core-without-ioptionst/) and [Rick Strahl's Web Log](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/may/23/strongly-typed-configuration-settings-in-aspnet-core)
but those are for alone strongly typed objects but not with configinjector.

I have tried both ways like

```
 services.Configure<MyConfigPath >(configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:MyConfigPath "));
```

and creating extension method specified by [StrathWeb Blog](https://www.strathweb.com/2016/09/strongly-typed-configuration-in-asp-net-core-without-ioptionst/) .

```
  services.ConfigurePOCO<MyConfigPath>(configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:MyConfigPath"));
```

Here chances of changing class library project are rare as that is been used by many other projects which are not on .net core yet.
Here is how my appsettings.json file

```
{
 "AppSettings": {
  "MyConfigPath": "C:\\EmployeeUpload"
  }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found way to solve the problem I was facing. Bit use of reflection helped me here.

Below is the solution

```
var type= typeof(MyConfigPath);
var t = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
PropertyInfo propertyInfo = type.GetProperty("Value");
var configValue = configuration.GetValue<string>($"AppSettings:{type.Name}");
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(configValue) && propertyInfo != null)
{
  propertyInfo.SetValue(t, configValue, null);
}
services.AddSingleton(type, t);
```

By this way I was able to inject my strongly typed classes. I used reflection because the same thing I have to do with many types in a class library.

I got this idea with some R&D and some discussion with my team.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you are using `.Configure` method, you will not be injecting `MyConfigPath`, but `IOptions<MyConfigPath>` (have another look at your first link). So your injection becomes something like this:

```
public MyClass(IOptions<MyConfigPath> myConfigPathOptions)
```

Secondly, `configuration.GetSection` is meant to access an entire section, not just a string. If you want to directly access "MyConfigPath" from the JSON you can use `configuration["AppSettings:MyConfigPath"]`. You can use `GetSection` like this `configuration.GetSection("AppSettings")`, to get all application settings as a whole.

I suggest you look into the documentation for [IConfiguration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=basicconfiguration) and [IOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

I assume what you are really trying to do is something like this:

Have a class for all your settings:

```
public class MyAppSettings {
    public string MyConfigPath {get; set;} 
    public int MyOtherSetting { get; set; } // sample of how you could have more
}
```

The json for the above with an added "MyOtherSetting" would look something like this:

```
{
    "AppSettings": {
        "MyConfigPath": "C:\\EmployeeUpload",
        "MyOtherSetting" : 501
    }
}
```

In your startup class, you can use this:

```
services.Configure<MyAppSettings>(configuration.GetSection("AppSettings")
```

Now, for injections, you will need to use something like this:

```
MyClass(IOptions<MyAppSettings> settingOptions)
{            
    _myConfigPath = myConfigPath.Value.MyConfigPath;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Neville Nazerane, actually I cant change constructor of MyClass. It should remain as it is. I can access the values of config keys by providing key like this : "AppSettings:MyConfigPath". It works actually.

Comment: you mean your injection is working? you found `myConfigPath.Value` to be null right?

Comment: either ways, using `services.AddSingleton` should help you keep your structure

Comment: yes, injection is working and myConfigPath.Value is null. here Value is property of abstract class ConfigurationSetting.

Comment: What I want here is that: myConfigPath.Value  should not be null. It should be assigned from configuration with injecting from startup..

Comment: if you can't change your `MyClass`, your options are using something like `.AddSingleton(new MyConfigPath{ Value = configuration["AppSettings:MyConfigPath"] })` or you can change your json into `"MyConfigPath:Value"` and you may still have to use a singleton method